# Using Integration by Parts to Justify the Derivative of a Tempered Distribution

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

From a textbook on Harmonic Analysis:

> [image]

**Question:** Why does integration by parts yield

$$
T_{f'}(φ) = ∫_ℝ f'(x)φ(x)dx = - ∫_{ℝ}f(x)φ'(x)dx = -T_f(φ')?
$$

**Attempt.** I know that Integration by Parts *does* yield that

$$
∫_{ℝ}f(x)φ(x)dx = ∫_ℝ f'(x)φ(x)dx + ∫_{ℝ}f(x)φ'(x)dx
$$

so that the equality would hold if $∫_{ℝ}f(x)φ(x)dx = 0$.

Comment: The formula in "Attempt" is incorrect.

Comment: $f(x)φ(x) = ∫_ℝ f'(x)φ(x)dx + ∫_{ℝ}f(x)φ'(x)dx$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a Schwartz function we have:

$\displaystyle \lim_{|x|\to \infty} f(x)φ(x)=0$

As a result, in other words, we have:

$\displaystyle  f(x)φ(x)|_{-\infty}^{\infty}=0$

In integration by parts we have:

$\displaystyle  ∫_ℝ f'(x)φ(x)dx + ∫_{ℝ}f(x)φ'(x)dx=f(x)φ(x)|_{-\infty}^{\infty} =0$

$\displaystyle \to ∫_ℝ f'(x)φ(x)dx=-∫_{ℝ}f(x)φ'(x)dx$

Comment: Similar as to Green theorems.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
T_{f'}(\varphi)&=\int_{\bf{R}}f'(x)\varphi(x)dx\\
&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-N}^{N}f'(x)\varphi(x)dx\\
&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(f(N)\varphi(N)-f(-N)\varphi(-N)-\int_{-N}^{N}f(x)\varphi'(x)dx\right)\\
&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}-\int_{-N}^{N}f(x)\varphi'(x)dx\\
&=-\int_{\bf{R}}f(x)\varphi'(x)dx\\
&=-T_{f}(\varphi').
\end{align*}